# Spring boot on openshift 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable

Tags: spring, spring-boot, openshift

I want to deploy Spring boot App on openshift

I've

.openshift/action_hooks/deploy file as

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x

if [ ! -d $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/m2/repository ]
then
    mkdir -p $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/m2/repository
fi

if [ ! -d $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/logs ]
then
    mkdir -p $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/logs
fi

if [ ! -d $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/apache-maven-3.3.9 ]
then
    wget -P $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR http://mirror.cc.columbia.edu/pub/software/apache/maven/maven-3/3.3.9/binaries/apache-maven-3.3.9-bin.tar.gz
    tar xvf $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/apache-maven*.tar.gz --directory $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR
    rm -f $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/apache-maven*.tar.gz
fi


export JAVA_HOME=/etc/alternatives/java_sdk_1.8.0
export M2=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms384m -Xmx412m"
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

cd $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR

$M2/mvn --version
$M2/mvn -s settings.xml clean install

# if you get error then un comment the following line
#$M2/mvn -s settings.xml package

nohup java -Xms384m -Xmx412m -jar target/*.jar --server.port=${OPENSHIFT_DIY_PORT} --server.address=${OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP} --spring.profiles.active=openshift &
```

and .openshift/action_hooks/start file as

```
#!/bin/bash

source $OPENSHIFT_CARTRIDGE_SDK_BASH

set -x

export JAVA_HOME=/etc/alternatives/java_sdk_1.8.0
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

cd $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR
nohup java -Xms384m -Xmx412m -jar target/*.jar --server.port=${OPENSHIFT_DIY_PORT} --server.address=${OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP} --spring.profiles.active=openshift &
```

and .openshift/action_hooks/stop file as

```
#!/bin/bash
source $OPENSHIFT_CARTRIDGE_SDK_BASH

# The logic to stop your application should be put in this script.
if [ -z "$(ps -ef | grep testrubyserver.rb | grep -v grep)" ]
then
    client_result "Application is already stopped"
else
    kill `ps -ef | grep testrubyserver.rb | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2 }'` > /dev/null 2>&1
fi
```

after deploying to openshift I get

```
Service Temporarily Unavailable

The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) Server at myapp-mydomain.rhcloud.com Port 80
```

how to resolve this problem???

Comment: I recommend checking logs of the app for more clues on the root cause, if the Maven build runs fine on OpenShift. The 503 generally means that your app is [not responding](https://developers.openshift.com/faq/troubleshooting.html#_why_am_i_getting_503_errors_service_temporarily_unavailable). Also, your stop hook seems to be unmodified (attempting to stop the default example ruby server that comes with the DIY cartridge).